# Transfinite induction and circles on the plane

Tags: set-theory

We need to prove that there is a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for every circle $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ we have that they intersect on exactly $3$ points,meaning $|A \cap C|=3$.

I know that $|C| = |\mathbb{R}| = \aleph$, so by AC we well-order the circles on the plane, for every ordinal $\alpha < \aleph$

1) If $\alpha = 0 $ we pick there random point from $C_0$ and put them into $A_0$ such that $|A_0 \cap C_0|=3$

2) If  $\alpha $   is successor then ...

3) If  $\alpha$ is a limit then ...

I am really stuck here, first time to see such thing, also in every step how i can make sure that $|A_{\alpha} \cap C_{\alpha}|=3$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At stage $\alpha$ you pick points from $C_\alpha$ to make three and add them to $A$.

At stage $0$ you pick any three points from $C_0$ and add them to $A$.  At stage $1$ you look how many points that are already in $A$ are on $C_1$, then pick enough points to make three.  At stage $2$ you look how many points of $C_2$ are already in $A$ and pick enough points to make three and so on.  When you pick points to add you have to avoid any that are on preceding circles, but that is easy.  There are less than continuum many preceding circles and each one only intersects the current circle in at most two points, so you have lots of points left to choose from.  What can go wrong is that at some stage you find there are already four or more points of the circle already in $A$, so you need to avoid that.  Again there are less than continuum many sets of three points so you can avoid all the circles that are determined.

Comment: If i pick just one point at a time, and make sure that it does not add to previous circle or add more than 3 points to all circles that are defined by any 3 points  on the set $A$ till now, then i can skip the part where i need to check if my circle have 4 points or more, is this correct ??

Comment: No.  The points you pick on $C_0$ through $C_3$ could possibly all be on $C_8$.  You also won't make sure there are three points on $C_0$ if you only put one in at stage $0$

Comment: at stage 0 i choose 3 random points on $C_0$, but in the inductive step i add  one point at a time and update the set, making sure on more than 3 points are in every circle on the plane by checking every three points already exist which define unique circle and i remove all points of this circle , i think this is valid, dont you ?

Comment: We require exactly three points on each circle.  Say one of the points on $C_0$ is also on $C_1$.  If you only add one more point from $C_1$ at stage $1$, when will a third point get added?

Comment: at every stage i make sure that in every $C_i$ there is three points but what i say is that i choose them one at a time and not the three instantly, i don't know if i am making my argument clear to you.

Comment: No, you are not.  I think you should choose enough at stage $i$ to have three points from $C_i$.  It sounds to me like you only want to add one point at stage $i$.  I suppose you could do that by adding one point from $C_0$ at stages $0,1,2$, then one point from $C_1$ at stages $3,4,5$ assuming we need three and so on, but it seems simpler to make each stage complete.